# QT how to check running system contains libraries

Tags: qt, qml

In QT how to check the running system contains library import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Comment: Can you explain the purpose?

Comment: Basically its a Qt5 component called `Quick`, which you find and link to your program in CMake (and something similar in .pro). Here you have the chance to notify the user about not finding the component through `find_package`.